# How do I get TeX to recognize my class?

Tags: document-classes

I have a file myclass.cls in a folder, and I made a new document that uses myclass. However,
my class isn't being recognized as existing. I'm using TeXworks on a PC. How can I get the class working?

Comment: They are already in the same folder

Comment: Do you have `\documentclass{myclass}` as the 1st line of your document? ... Ah, welcome to TeX.SX! (Well, it should be the effective 1st line, of course ;-))

Comment: In addition: Is `myclass.cls` really a class?